Milnor construction on principal bundles
By way of example, suppose we have principal bundle of orthonormal frames on a manifold $M$
$$SO(n)\hookrightarrow PM\rightarrow M.$$
Does there exist a construction (I'm aiming at at least a reference) for the classifying space of principal bundle, i.e.
$$BSO(n)\hookrightarrow BPM\rightarrow M?$$
A further example would be as follows. Let $\tilde{X}\rightarrow X$ a two-sheeted covering space, i.e. $\mathbb{Z}_2$ principal bundle. In doing Milnor construction one gets $$B\mathbb{Z}_2=\mathbb{R}P^\infty\hookrightarrow \tilde{X}\star_X\tilde{X}\star_X\dots\star_X\tilde{X}\rightarrow X$$
Is there any existing literature on the topic?
EDIT:
I've found something in the preface of Lurie: Higher topos theory. One should study groupoid-valued sheaves or stacks which describe fibrations with fibre BG, which is not homotopy equivalent to a discrete space anymore.

There is no such thing. The fibers of a principal bundle are not copies of $G$, they are copies of $G$-torsors; they don't have a group structure so you can't take their classifying space.

Milnor construction does not require group structure. It requires only group translations (free action), join however is a topological construction.
